# The End of the Rainbow

Tags: word-search

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

"And there we are, the end of the rainbow!"
You glance around, the scenery looks...actually just like any other grassy field around a lake, but the surface of the lake itself harbors many beautiful colo(u)rs. You then look at your guide, he looks horrified, his eyes staring at the lake. After a bit, he tells you something's wrong and runs away.

You look at the lake once more, and your mind begins to visualize the colo(u)rs...

[image: Word search]

> Red (3, 5, 6, 7, 10)
> Brown (4)
> Orange (4, 6)
> Yellow (4, 6)
> Green (3, 4, 5)
> Green-Blue/Blue-Green (4, 4, 4, 9)
> Blue (4, 6, 11)
> Purple (6)
> Pink (4, 7, 7)

**What colo(u)r is off in the lake, and who created it?**

Text version of the grid:

```
U V I O L E T N A Y C
L O M R A U U I D E R
T A A A E T R N O L I
R I G N T L Q D F L M
A S E G A O U I P O S
M H N E R L O G I W O
A C T S T I I O N J N
R U A P A V S L K A Y
I F L A M E E D C D V
N O O R A M A E S E A
E V E R M I L L I O N
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After solving most of the word search, I got to this point:

> [image]
>
>  The words I found were:
>
>  Red (red, flame, maroon, crimson, vermillion)
>  Brown (seal)
>  Orange (tart, orange)
>  Yellow (gold, yellow)
>  Green (sea, jade, olive)
>  Green-Blue/Blue-Green (cyan, teal, turquoise)
>  Blue (4, navy, indigo, ultramarine)
>  Purple (violet)
>  Pink (pink, fuchsia, magenta)
>
>  I am missing one 4-letter blue word. This could be LILA along the main diagonal, but in English that would normally be called lilac.
>
>  The unused letters spell "oeuatofspaces". Clearly it should be "outofspace" so there are surplus letters E, A, and S. The final S could be removed by moving SEA there; I found SEA elsewhere in the grid but in a place where all those letters are already used up by other words. Removing the E and A is only possible by using TAEL instead of TEAL, so maybe that is the "Colour that is off in the lake". I already found TEAL elsewhere, but this time not all its letters were already used.
>
>  The result is that we have the Colour Out Of Space, which is a story created by [H.P. Lovecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colour_Out_of_Space)  .

**Edit:**
After the corrections in the grid (see comments), the result is this:

> [image]
>
>  Red (red, flame, maroon, crimson, vermillion)
>  Brown (seal)
>  Orange (tart, orange)
>  Yellow (gold, yellow)
>  Green (sea, jade, olive)
>  Green-Blue/Blue-Green (teal, teal, turquoise)
>  Blue (cyan, navy, indigo, ultramarine)
>  Purple (violet)
>  Pink (pink, fuchsia, magenta)
>
>  The colour that is off is teal, cause that is used twice.
>  (Note that SEA is also still found twice in the grid, but you can ignore the diagonal one - it was too much work to remove the line in my picture).

Comment: Alright so, there is indeed a switch of two letters (which I will fix), as for the missing color. Vg vf plna, V pbafvqrerq plna nf n "oyhr" pbybe engure guna oyhr-terra, znxvat gur frpbaq grny gur ynfg oyhr-terra pbybe lbh arrq.

Comment: @Auribouros, while you are fixing things, I'm guessing the mis-spelling of fuhcsia is also unintentional. I didn't want to comment on them earlier, as I wan't sure if they were an integral part of the what was "off".

Comment: I'm still a little confused over which word I missed.

Comment: Grny vf hfrq gjvpr, nyfb V punatrq plna gb oyhr-terra

Comment: @Auribouros Fuchsia is still wrong. It is named after a German botanist called Fuchs, which is how I remember to spell it.

Comment: Next time I'll just write "hot pink" or something

Comment: Sbe grny orvat gurer gjvpr: znxvat jbeq frnepurf vf uneq. Ohg gur bss pbybe vf qrsvavgryl gur yrsgbire yrggref!